# How to clear the array index using jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

```
var items=[];

items.push(data);
```

I am using an array to store my data, and then submit using ajax. For the first time submission, it works fine. But when submit subsequently, it will submit null value together with data passing to server.

I am using the method below to clear the array, but i found that the previous data just set to null. For example, for the first time i passed value 1, successful. For the second submission, i clear the array and store new value, e.g. i pushed value 2 to the items[], when submit it will submit null and 2.

```
items.splice(0);
```

How can i fix it? I need to reset the array every time submit the value.

Code:

```
var items=[];
$("#selection").click(function(e) {
       $(":checkbox").each(function() {
            if(this.checked === false) {
                this.checked = true;
                items.push(this.id);
            }
        });
});

$('#grid').submit(function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
            var formdata = {
                data:items
            };
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "/add",
                data: formdata ,
                dataType:'html',
                success: function(data) {
                    alert("added");
                }
            });
        });
```

Comment: add all relevatn code

Comment: Would be helpful to see relevant code as guradio mentioned but what's stopping you from reassigning the variable?

Comment: `items.length = 0` or just reassign a new, empty array `items = []`. (Regardless, this isn't a jQuery problem, it's a plain JavaScript thing.)

Comment: I think the problem occurred due to pagination ;(

Comment: Your existing code that calls `items.push()` from inside a click handler seems a bit strange - wouldn't that mean that the same values get added to the array multiple times if the user clicks that element multiple times before submitting?

Comment: If checked, the data will be pushed else will remove the item.

Comment: I have a big problem due to the pagination which maybe is the root cause of the problem.

Answer (score 2):

You simply set the array to a empty array after the ajax

```
success: function(data) {
    alert("added");
    items=[];
}
```

or better empty it at each click

```
$("#selection").click(function(e) {
items=[];
// rest of the code
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to reset all array till leave it empty you can do this :

```
var array = [1,2,3,4,5,6];
array.length = 0;
```

it that way you can reset your array

### Updated

when you use :

```
array.splice(0) // this will delete items from index that you passed, only if you passed the first parameters
```

Hope it helps you.

Thank you for the note @nnnnnn

Comment: *"this will clone the entire array"* - The `.splice()` method doesn't clone, it modifies, and `.splice(0)` does empty an array.

Comment: @nnnnnn OMG your right I got confused with array.slice(0) method that will clone the entire array, sorry I will update the answer thank you.